# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am in the process of migrating an existing platform to a new server.  I am taking the opportunity to upgrade PHP ect and standardise/debug the code as the previous maintainers have had different standards.

I have opted for PHP version 5.4.33 for now, once I have managed to move everything over to mysqli I will look to go to a more recent version.  I didnt think anything server side would make a difference to AJAX/JS?  As far as I am aware is it not client side?

Since I have moved the code over I am having issues with AJAX/JS.  I am not the greatest at AJAX/JS and could use some assistance please.  Even though every submit works differently through the entire platform I do not want to remove the AJAX/JS that already exists.  I will most likely use it as an opportunity to how to use it as it makes end user experience smoother.

Using Chrome to debug I am receiving the following error on clicking the Save button:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
email_user
onclick
```

This is the Save button code

```
<span id="loading" style="color: red; font-size: x-small; display: none; text-decoration: blink;">Loading... Please wait..</span><input type="button" value="Save" class="save" onclick="if(validate()){ email_user(); }" />
```

This is the function code for validate()

```
function validate() {

    var errorString = "";

    if(isBlank(document.getElementById("forename").value)) {
        errorString += " - Please input a forename\n";
    }
    if(isBlank(document.getElementById("surname").value)) {
        errorString += " - Please input a surname\n";
    }
    if(isBlank(document.getElementById("company_name").value)) {
        errorString += " - Please select a company\n";
    }

    if(document.getElementById("username").value != "" || document.getElementById("password").value != "") {
        if(isBlank(document.getElementById("username").value)) {
            errorString += " - Please input a username\n";
        }
        if(isBlank(document.getElementById("password").value)) {
            errorString += " - Please select a password\n";
        }
    }

    //if not a solicitor then cases mandatory
    if(document.getElementById("company_role_type_id").value == 2) { 
        if(document.getElementById("other_view_if").value == "") {
            errorString += " - Please select who can view your cases\n";
        }
    }
    if(document.getElementById("company_role_type_id").value == 3) { 
        if(document.getElementById("other_view_ea").value == "") {
            errorString += " - Please select who can view your cases\n";
        }
    }

    if(errorString) {
        alert('Please correct the following items:-\n\n'+ errorString);
        return false;
    }
    else {

        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the function code for email_user()

```
function email_user(){

if(skip_email == true){ $('user').submit(); }

var url  = 'email_user.php';
var params = '?' + $('user').serialize() + '&from_edit=1';

$('loading').style.display = 'inline';

var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(
                    url,
                    {
                            method: 'get',
                            parameters: params,
                            onComplete: show_response
                    });

function show_response(this_request){

//alert(this_request.responseText);

    var reply = this_request.responseText.evalJSON(true);

    if(reply['status'] == false){ var blah = ''; }

    else{ alert(reply['message']); }

//$('loading').style.display = 'none';

    $('user').submit();

    }

}
```

Thinking about it, maybe it is more to do with the Apache version??  Just in case Apache version is 2.2.15.

Any assistance you guys can give me will be greatly appreciated!  If you need any more information please let me know.

Kind Regards,

n00bstacker

Comment: I´ve noticed that your selector is not ok, $("loading") should be $("#loading"). Try to apply that change and tell how it works...

Comment: What is `$` here?  Is a library in use?  Is `$` just an alias for getElementById?

Comment: $('loading').style.display = 'inline'; <- it's trying to find <loading> and set the style display to "inline".

Comment: Also, there is other issue if you´re using jquery: try this: $('#loading').css("display","inline");

Comment: This line won´t also work: $('user').submit(), set the "user" selector accordingly if a class $(".user"), if it's an id $("#user"). I'm guessing that #user is the form name?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys!  You guys answer quicker than I can test!  Have upped Guillermo as he found both issues and was very detailed.  Thanks to all though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously stated in comments, your code has some issues, your line (the one that is triggering the error, can be optimized in the following way:

```
$('#loading').css("display","inline"); //Selector is ok now...
```

In the other hand, I also noticed that you have a second selector $('user') that won´t work. Remember that anything without a dot, or a sharp will be considered as an element selector (loading, and user elements, won´t exist in your document unless you created it.

Remember:

```
$("#myId") //id selector
$(".myClass") //class selector
```

If "user" is the form name, the code may work. Remember that you want to catch the form submit event.

Regards,

Guillermo

Comment: Thank you very much Guillermo!  Yours comments and answer was very clear and detailed.  I knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `$('loading')` to `$('#loading')`?